# SQL pivot columns null (code/results included)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been playing with the SQL Fiddle, and am very close to being done - I just want some help on getting the column data returned ( I think the column varchar title with two words (example: High Value) is throwing it off.

This is query I'm struggling with:

```
SELECT Velocity
  , [Very High]
  , High
  , [Medium]
  , [Low]
  , [Very Low]
  , [Total]
FROM (
  SELECT CASE 
      WHEN GROUPING(velocity) = 0 THEN CAST(velocity AS CHAR(7))
      ELSE 'Total'
    END AS velocity
    , CASE 
      WHEN GROUPING(volume) = 0 THEN CAST(volume AS CHAR(7))
      ELSE 'Total'
    END AS volume
    , SUM(Sales) AS Sales
  FROM test1
  GROUP BY velocity, volume
  WITH CUBE
  ) AS s
PIVOT(SUM(Sales) FOR volume IN ([Very High], [High], [Medium], [Low], [Very Low], [Total])) AS p;
```

I'm expecting to see this result:
[image: Result wanted here:]

Adding a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49d14/31)

Comment: even when a fiddle help, you need put more info in your question because sometime sql fiddle isnt working and ppl wont be able to see it.

Comment: Apologies! Long story short,  under my columns 'Very High' and 'Very Low', I get NULL values in my query. Yet under the column name 'High' or 'Medium' I return values just fine.

Comment: SELECT Velocity, [Very High], High, [Medium],[Low],[Very Low],[Total]
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(velocity)=0 THEN CAST(velocity AS CHAR(7)) ELSE 'Total' END AS velocity,
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(volume)=0 THEN CAST(volume AS CHAR(7)) ELSE 'Total' END AS volume,
    SUM(Sales) AS Sales
  FROM test1
  GROUP BY velocity, volume WITH CUBE
) AS s
PIVOT( SUM(Sales) FOR volume IN ([Very High], [High], [Medium],[Low],[Very Low], [Total]) ) AS p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found mistake in your SQL query. You need to change `CAST(volume AS CHAR(7)) to CAST(volume AS CHAR(12))` Otherwise you have in your inner temp table values like "Very Hi" and "Very Lo".

Comment: Simply check my answer as useful or as solution to your task